# SMB is giving me NIGHTMARES, shares show but I can't access any folders

Tags: permissions, smb

Need a little help setting up the SMB server. I haven't been using Linux in quite a while and am wanting to dump Windows and use this box as strictly a file server for my media player boxes scattered around my house.

I don't need security on the shares at all as they are strictly on an internal network and the media players don't seem to want to work with shares requiring passwords.

Here's the thing: I've been out of this so long I'm pretty much a newbie again, the computer shows up when I try to add a new media folder in the media player, but even if I use my Ubuntu user name and password I can't access the folder, and the logs show an attempt by user `nobody`, session closed. when I try to access the folder in Ubuntu, I can access `smb://main pc` and it shows all the folders but I can't get into anything. Even using my Ubuntu credentials just gives me a damn error saying permission denied. I know I'm probably overlooking something easy that's gonna make me look like a real dunce, but any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Well I recommend to do the following from the kickoff. All commands to be run are root user or with sudo to avoid privilege issues.

1. Install samba service packages.

> ```
> sudo apt-get install samba samba-common python-glade2 system-config-samba
> ```

2. Backup Samba default config file.

> cp /etc/samba/smb.cnf /etc/samba/smb.cnf.bak

3. Create Required directory location- preferably a large volume for max storage.

> mkdir -p /data/SambaShare/PublicShare

4. Change permission and ownership of created directories.

> chmod -R 0775 /data/SambaShare/PublicShare
>
> chown -R nobody:nogroup /data/SambaShare/PublicShare

5. Edit samba config file
   According to your requirements edit the following entries.

> vi /etc/samba/smb.cnf

```
[PublicShare]
comment = My Public Share
path = /data/SambaShare/PublicShare
writable = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.
guest ok = yes
```

*Note: Assuming your internal IP range starts with 192.168.xx.x, so y **host allow =** in the above code has 192.168. if it differs in your case try editing accordingly, but dont miss the spaces given between host's range.*

The PublicShare folder is now accessible by all without user and password. If you require Group and User for managing you can, then you need to add "**valid users =** "in the above code. You can opt your preferred name and change accondingly. Codes are self explainatory.

6. Add a group for Samba "mysmbgrp":

> ```
> addgroup mysmbgrp
> ```

7. Add a user for group mysmbgrp

> ```
> adduser user1 -G mysmbgrp
> ```

8. Assign a password form samba users to login

> ```
> smbpasswd -a user1
> ```

9. Enable user account for Samaba login.

> ```
> smbpasswd -e user1
> ```

10. Restart services.

> ```
> sudo service smbd stop
>
> sudo service nmbd stop
>
> sudo service smbd start
>
> sudo service nmbd start
> ```

Comment: I'll give that a shot, everything is the same in my configuration except for the chmod and chow,  I'll make a test directory to see if that solves it, all the folders show up, but I can't get into them still, but I'll do that and see if it does the trick, thanks.

Comment: Well that didn't work..... worked once with a single folder, but no go when I tried to share any other folders..... I'll just have to keep playing with it I suppose until I get it down and keep using windows u til I figure it out, I have 6tb of video files that need to be able to be accessed from four different media players (almost 2500 movies and 280,000 music tracks). Lol, call me a media junkie...

Comment: are you sure, the the folder you share has given the required statements I gave in smb.conf. Kindly recheck and moreover recheck the ownership and permissions of other folders and files as well. I am sure you are missing somewhere. Make sure you followed the steps fully without missing.

Comment: This is a really excellent write up. I've been messing around with samba for hours and just starting from scratch with this got it done in 15 mins.